# ISSUE: Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I built this to test reports against csv files containing the data but I am running into this error "Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined" . Please advise thanks.  Below is my code

```
testReport: async function (driver, dataFile) {
        var data = await csv({ noheader: true, output: "csv" }).fromFile("./admin/data/" + dataFile);
        var trs = await driver.findElements(By.css('.qa-report', 'tbody', 'tr'));
        //trs.shift(); // remove first tr - it's the header row
        var errors = [];
        for (var i in data) {
            var row = data[i];
            var tds = await trs[i].findElements(By.tagName('td'));
            for (var j in row) {
                var csvData = data[i][j];
                var siteData = await tds[j].getText();
                if (siteData != csvData) {
                    errors.push("[" + i + "," + j + "] - expected(" + csvData + ") got(" + siteData + ")");
                }
            }
        }

        if (errors.length > 0) {
            errorMessage = "Cells failed to validate:";
            for (var i in errors) {
                errorMessage += "\n" + errors[i];
            }
            throw new Error(errorMessage);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. `j` is not used to loop through `tds`,  it's used to loop through `row`. this is why.

Comment: instead of `for (var j in row) {` try `for (var j in tds) {`

Answer (score 0):

Your iterators looks a bit messed up (as already commented)

try `for (var j in tds) {` instead of `for (var j in row) {`

I guess you have more result rows than columns per row. If you still have problems, post the class definitions for `findElements` or `By`which we don't know.

Comment: ok I fixed the loop but now it is throwing "Cannot read property 'findElements' of undefined"  not sure why?

`or (var j in tds) {
                var csvData = data[i][j];
                var siteData = await tds[j].getText();
                if (siteData != csvData) {
                    errors.push("[" + i + "," + j + "] - expected(" + csvData + ") got(" + siteData + ")");
                }
            }`